# Loading library with dependency with QLibrary

Tags: qt, qlibrary

Suppose I have two libraries, `A.dll` and `B.dll`. The library `A` depends on `B`. I want to load `A` into my project.

My project is in `C:/Project`. If I keep both `A.dll` and `B.dll` in `C:/Project`, I can load `A` with:

```
QLibrary lib("A"); 
lib.load();
```

This works fine. `load()` will return false if `B.dll` isn't in `C:/Project`, though.

The problem is I want to keep both `A.dll` and `B.dll` in `C:/Project/lib`. But when I move both libs to that location and try to load:

```
QLibrary lib("C:/Project/lib/A");
lib.load();
```

It fails. But this works if I keep `A.dll` in `C:/Project/lib` and `B.dll` in `C:/Project`.

How can I keep both libs in `C:/Project/lib`and have `A.dll` load successfully?

**Edit:** the error message I get is `"Cannot load library C:/Project/lib/A . The specified module could not be found."`

Comment: Could you please print out the error string by  << lib.errorString()` and then share it with us?

Comment: Sure, just updated the question with it.

Comment: I think `QLibrary lib("C:/Project/lib/A");` may be in appropriate. I would personally keep the `QLibrary lib("A");` original version, and put the "C:\Project\lib\" into the search path. Can you try that please and let me know the result? You could try `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(const QString& path)` where the path is the aforementioned one.

Comment: It worked. I used SetDllDirectory() as DmitryARN recommended, and kept QLibrary lib("A");.

Comment: Please also try the Qt solution and let me know if it works. It is not ideal to use Windows specific API in a Qt (cross-platform) application if there are qt alternatives for that API. This way, you could reduce the platform specific detail to a string, and not API, which would be a neater solution in the Qt world IMHO. We need to improve Qt if that API does not help, so that is why I would like to know it. :)

Comment: I replaced the SetDllDirectory() call with `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath(QDir::currentPath().append("/lib"));`.
It didn't work. Also tried writing the path by hand with `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("C:/Project/lib");`, same result.

Comment: OK, if it does not work with hard coded absolute path (including a backslash trial for the path separator, too), right after initialization the application, then it would make a good feature request, at least in QtWinExtras as the last resort. Btw, make sure you have a qcoreapplication instance.

Comment: I have a QGuiApplication instance. I tried `app.addLibraryPath()` using both QDir and the hardcoded absolute path, including using backslashes (actually double backslashes, cause it was trying to escape characters). Same results, couldn't load the library.

Comment: hmm, that is a pity, but thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SetDllDirectory, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should add into your system environment the path to C:/Project/lib, or from the Projects tab into your QT Creator edit the Path variable(add the path to your libraries)